# Returning value from a Scala Future

Tags: scala, functional-programming, flatmap

In the below code, I'm trying to do two operations. One, to create a customer in a db, and the other, to create an event in the db. The creation of the event, is dependent on the creation of the user.

I'm new to Scala, and confused on the role of Futures here. I'm trying to query a db and see if the user is there, and if not, create the user. The below code is supposed to check if the user exists with the `customerByPhone()` function, and if it doesn't, then go into the `createUserAndEvent()` function.

What it's actually doing, is skipping the response from `customerByPhone` and going straight into `createUserAndEvent()`. I thought that by using a flatmap, the program would automatically wait for the response and that I wouldn't have to use `Await.result` is that not the case? Is there a way to avoid using `Await.result` to not block the thread on production code?

```
override def findOrCreate(phoneNumber: String, creationReason: String): Future[AvroCustomer] =  {
  //query for customer in db
  //TODO this goes into createUserAndEvent before checking that response comes back empty from querying for user
  customerByPhone(phoneNumber)
    .flatMap(_ => createUserAndEvent(phoneNumber, creationReason, 1.0))
}
```

Comment: I'd consider looking into upsert support from your DB instead. Maybe your DB library has native support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use Await.result or any other blocking.  You do in fact have the result from customerByPhone, you're just ignoring it with the _ . I think what you want is something like this:

```
customerByPhone(phoneNumber)
  .flatMap(customer => {
    if(customer == null)
      createUserAndEvent(phoneNumber, creationReason, 1.0)
    else
      Future(customer)
   })
```

You need to code the logic to do something only if the customer isn't there.

Comment: BTW, this is a similar answer to both answers to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726050/scala-future-not-entering-oncomplete) on this topic, though without discussing onComplete.